# With query Issue in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have following query which works fine and gives result for StatusType

```
AddOnModel::with('StatusType')->get();
```

But when I write below, it does not bind StatusType Records

```
AddOnModel
::select(\DB::Raw('A.AddOnID, A.AddOn, Count(R.AddOnID) as Total'))
->from( 'tblAddOn as A' )
->with('StatusType')
->leftjoin( 'tblrevenue as R', \DB::raw( 'R.AddOnID' ), '=', \DB::raw( 'A.AddOnID' ) )
->groupBy("A.AddOnID", "A.AddOn")->get();
```

The part which does not work is this one: `->with('StatusType')`

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is the Model

```
class AddOnModel extends Model {

    public $table = 'tbladdon';
    public $primaryKey = 'AddOnID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function StatusType() {
        return $this->hasOne('\StatusTypeModel', 'StatusTypeID', 'StatusTypeID');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this as a solution, make toArray() method in AddOn model, make that method returns what you need id, name, etc, like this:

```
return [
   'id' => $this->id,
   'StatusType' => this->StatusType
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `with()` after `->leftjoin` may be this will affect. Try below code:

```
AddOnModel::with('StatusType')
->select(\DB::Raw('A.AddOnID, A.AddOn, Count(R.AddOnID) as Total'))
->from( 'tblAddOn as A' )
->leftjoin( 'tblrevenue as R', \DB::raw( 'R.AddOnID' ), '=', \DB::raw( 'A.AddOnID' ) )
->groupBy("A.AddOnID", "A.AddOn")
->get();
```

Hpoe this will work for you.